# Why is Adobe Illustrator printing (on paper) an inverted color scheme?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, vector

I recently reformatted my computer (full factory reformat, the full 9) so everything is back to default (including program settings) and I came across an issue I've never had or even seen before. I created an 8.5 x 11" Illustrator file and placed a black logo in the center so I could print it on paper and the printer inverted the colors (black bg with a white logo) wasting an ungodly amount of black ink. I thought it was an artboard issue so I put an 8.5x11 white square behind it and it printed inverted again. My blood pressure hit its rev limiter. I'm afraid to print another sheet until I know exactly what's going on because it's wasting an incredible amount of ink.

Comment: Check the **Print options**

Comment: Hardware support questions are generally off-topic here on GDSE.  Can you please take some time to read the [help page on what questions you can ask](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's your case but...

In my case I can change it in:

Output > Image: Negative.

In these  modes: Separations or In-RIP Separations selected.

Note that it's not available in Composite mode.

[image]